# Get meta.method from function handle?

Tags: matlab, metaclass

Suppose I have a function handle to a method:

`fc = @ici.get_performance;`

which, as a matter of fact, is translated by Matlab to

`fc = @(varargin)ici.get_performance(varargin{:})`

Is there any direct or indirect way to get the corresponding `meta.method` object?  The following works:

`m = metaclass(ici); fc2 = m.MethodList(strcmp({m.MethodList.Name}, 'get_performance'));`

but how do I get a reference to the object to which `fc` is bound, that I can pass to `metaclass`?  `meta.method(fc)` results in an error (*Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.  Class 'meta.method' is declared as Abstract.*), and `metaclass(fc)` gives me the `function_handle` class.

The use case is that I want to write a helper function to tell me in what file a particular method is defined, and passing a function handle should be the most straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will struggle here. Plain function handles like `@ici.get_performance` really only  know the string name of that function. In particular, it's not a handle to an instance method of class `ici` - but it might be a handle to a static method of that class, or a free function in the package `ici`.

MATLAB dispatches to object methods based on input arguments, as we can see here

```
h1 = @MException.getReport
h2 = @getReport
obj = MException('some:id', 'some string')
h1(obj) % fails - no such method
h2(obj) % succeeds.
```

In conclusion, I think you actually need to use MATLAB's [WHICH](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/which.html) function; however, unfortunately this is likely to be problematic since it isn't really all that well suited to programmatic use of that type.